# Getting tweetID with twitteroauth

Tags: php, twitter

I am using the code of Abraham to connect to tweeter and send my own tweet and until now so good.
My problem is that I need the tweetID when I post my new tweet but I cant figure out how to get it?

I use this code:

```
$tweet = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $oAuthToken, $oAuthSecret);

// Post the status message
$tweetMessage="Welcome to my mundo !!";
$tweet->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $tweetMessage));

var_dump($tweet);
echo $tweet->http_code ; //$tweet->status";

?>
```

When I do the dump I can't find the id_str , somebody told me that it is the unique ID ?

How could I get tweetID from this code?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

If you get your tweet posted to twitter successfully, you'll get a json data values when you use

```
var_dump($tweet);
echo $tweet->id_str;
```

$tweet->id_str will give you only the tweet id as you needed.